# How to assign DNS names to different web server under local network

Tags: router, dns, port-forwarding, redirection, dynamic-dns

I have three webservers in my home LAN (domotics, videosurveillance, Synology NAS). Right now, to access them from a remote client, I've set up a Dynamic DNS service and set the router (an Asus AC68U) to forward different ports to each local address.

What I would like to achieve, ideally, is a different subdomain for each web server so that I don't have to specify the port in the browser address bar. I.e., something like `nas.mydomainname.ddns.net` redirecting to my NAS local address and so on.

As far as I understand, I can't use DNS SRV records for HTTP requests. What other options do I have? Is there something I could do with the ASUS router? Or could I use the Synology NAS to redirect the connections to the other two servers based on the subdomain name?

Comment: set up a http proxy on machine which have the public ip (nas.mydomainname.ddns.net)

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate of _something_ but can't find what. Either way, use a reverse proxy.

Comment: Good suggestion from Ipor. Nginx could do the reverse proxy very easily. Unfortunately, I doubt the router (Asus) would support this kind of functionality.

Comment: The router doesn't have to. You can let one of the webservers handle it.

Comment: or a raspberry pi, nginx, sni, letsencrypt, https, reverse proxy....is what you should do.  just cname 3 subdomains to your dyn dns

Comment: @IporSircer can you elaborate a bit on that? Do you think the Synology NAS can do this sort of thing?

Comment: @grawity the same question to you. The only webserver that has some degree of configuration is the Synology NAS, which should also have a webserver application I think.

Comment: synology nas is a fully installed linux as i know

Comment: @Ipor, well actually I found that the user interface has already a tab for reverse proxies! I think this will do!

Comment: @IporSircer, I was able to configure the NAS as a reverse proxy and I can now login successfully to the nas itself and to the DVR via HTTPS. I can't login to the domotics webserver though (also HTTPS), as I have a login loop: I enter the credentials and then the login page appears again. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to add your server name and ip to hosts file. I don't think that your router can reassign DNS zones.

The second way to use bind DNS server in mixed mode (as cached and authority server) on your server. Then configure router's DHCP server to new DNS server.